# Efficient way of counting observations in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, loops, for-loop

I have the following question. I have a Python database containing clients of a hotel according to their country of origin (first two columns):

```
  Hotel name Country  Count
0    Hotel A      US      2
1    Hotel A      UK      1
2    Hotel A      US      2
3    Hotel B      UK      2
4    Hotel B      UK      2
```

This means, in Hotel A 2 clientes were from US and 1 from UK and in Hotel B they had 2 clients from UK and no clients from US. What **I want is the third column**, this means, the number of observations by country of origin that a hotel has. Up to now the only way in which I managed to do this is using a for loop, but as I have 10 million observations I wonder if there's a more efficient/faster way.

Comment: can you provide the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is colum 3, df['count'].

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` Hotel/country and `transform('count')`:

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Hotel name', 'Country']).transform('count')
```

output:

```
  Hotel name Country  Count
0    Hotel A      US      2
1    Hotel A      UK      1
2    Hotel A      US      2
3    Hotel B      UK      2
4    Hotel B      UK      2
```

Comment: Thanks! It makes total sense. But it output "Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1". Any idea why?

Comment: did you run exactly what is above? or something different?

Comment: `df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Hotel name', 'Country']).agg('count')` is an alternative here.

Comment: @Learningisamess no, this one would perform an aggregation, not transformation ;)

Comment: I swear I just copied and pasted the code above.

Comment: @mozway Indeed!

Comment: When I do print(df.groupby(['Hotel name', 'Country']).transform('count')) I have:
Empty DataFrame Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...]

Comment: Which pandas version are you using?

Comment: Pandas version 1.3.4

Comment: @EleanorAbernathy sorry I see no reason why this doesn't work. Try to copy the minimal example in a new notebook/script and make sure the issue is reproducible